# Weight in cts:collection-query

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I want perform a weighted search in [cts:collection-query](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:collection-query). Is there any way provided for this?

What exactly I want to do is I want to fetch documents from a collection and give them different weight in a similar way as we do in [cts:element-range-query](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-range-query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cts:collection-query` does not have any scoring options, unlike `cts:element-range-query`. A document either matches a collection query or it doesn't.

One option for you is to move the information you're current modeling with collections into elements (or JSON properties) within the documents; then you'll be able to use `cts:element-range-query`.

You haven't specified what kind of information you're using the collections for; it's hard to picture typical collection names benefitting from this approach. Some more detail might make that more clear.

If documents in some collections are "better" (should score higher) than ones in other collections, and those valuations are static, you could set the document quality based on the collections it belongs to. Not exactly the same, but perhaps that accomplishes the goal.